# Shell extension for SharePoint libraries

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sharepoint, shell-extensions

Is there a shell extension for Windows Explorer that is optimized for SharePoint libraries. Expected features are:

- Displaying Check-in/check-out status (as an icon overlay or additional column)
- Context menu to allow check-in/check-out/undo check-out, etc.
- Displaying current document version number
- Displaying document version history